# Upgrade tomcat 7.0.59 to 7.0.61 : Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: java, session, tomcat

We are upgrading from Tomcat 7.0.59 to 7.0.61 and getting following error.

This error occurs only when passing via Apache proxy (no SSL).

When calling the Tomcat context from the browser (without Apache proxy) it works without problems.

Has anyone experienced the same/similar problem ?

We did go through the changelog (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html) but we could not find any change explaining this behavior in Tomcat 7.0.61

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CaptchaServlet] in context with path [/cw] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:3008)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2384)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:897)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:909)
    at be.servlet.CaptchaServlet.doGet(CaptchaServlet.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code concerned is:

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    Captcha captcha = getNumberCaptcha(_width, _height, 5, Color.black);

    session.setAttribute(NAME, captcha);

    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private,no-cache,no-store");
    resp.setContentType("image/png");


    // See https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/KnownIssues#ImageIOIssues
    // Wrap insite MyImageIOOutputStream
    ImageIO.write(captcha.getImage(), "png", new MyImageIOOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream()));

    resp.getOutputStream().flush();
    resp.getOutputStream().close();

}
```

Before you start saying it is the ImageIO we did use the MyImageIOOutputStream as specified on the https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/KnownIssues#ImageIOIssues.

We even tried with loading an image from File into a byte array and sending the byte array in the resonse (so no making use of ImageIO), but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is surprising to find that this error occurs in Tomcat 7.0.61 but not in 7.0.59. The error basically says that you are creating a session after the header of the HTTP response has been sent. This is a problem because the session requires cookies and the cookies are transferred in the HTTP response headers. So it's too late to send the cookies.

Assuming that the CaptchaServlet is your code, the easiest solution is to create the session (`getSession()`) before your write any output in the servlet. Then you are on the safe side with any servlet container.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to the Java code. As mentioned, bypassing het proxy solves the problem (but of course no option in a PROD environment). Pretty weird.

Comment: If your code starts writing output and later starts a session (and therefore updates the cookies), everything depends on whether the output has been buffered or already sent downstream. So the proxy can indeed change the behavior (in particular if you switch from the HTTP protocol to AJP protocol, which is usually is with proxies). Furthermore, fixing the Java code will reliably get rid of this error under all circumstances.

Comment: Hi, I added the code concerned. If you see something wrong I'll be glad to hear all about it! But I don't see it (as mentioned before, this code has been running for the past 5 year on PROD (proxy-SSL) and never giving any problem.

Comment: If line 127 is `HttpSession session = req.getSession();`, then it's strange indeed. Your code has the correct sequence for working with sessions. Is this servlet directly called or is it the result of an internal forward?

Comment: Hi, the servlet is directly called.

Comment: I recommend that you further analyze the cause by running Tomcat in the debugger and settings a break point at org.apache.coyote.Response.setCommitted(). Then you'll find the culprit that commits the response. I have done this before and it can be enlightening. Of course, you'll need to simulate the proxy.

Comment: Hi, thx again for your input. We will do that. If you can point me to some links about how debugging Tomcat and setting breakpoints that would be great. We will need to setup a separate environment. As I'm working on another project right now this will be postponed till end of this month. I keep you posted...

Comment: I debug Tomcat from Eclipse. Just make sure you have Tomcat's source files attached. Then you can start your web project and set a break point in the desired Tomcat class. It's isn't different from debugging your web application (unless you use a different servlet container for development).

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that I have the same issue than you (in my particular case, 7.0.62 vs 7.0.59). My app works fine behind the apache proxy if Tomcat version is 7.0.59 but I have the same trace than you if I use 7.0.62 behind the proxy.

In my opinion we should report it to Tomcat as soon as possible

Comment: Hi, Yes , but I suppose we need the debugging info to give some body to the report. I don't know when you can do some debugging (see comment above) but over here it will take a few weeks as we are working on another project.